# how add text in string using sed

Tags: sed

I have command to find domain name of user which shows correct domain

```
domain=$(ui $user |grep -oP 'UDomain:.\K.*')
echo $domain
```

now I want to add domain in command

```
sed -i '/DB_COLLATE/a \ define('FTP_USER', 'design@$domain’);’ file.php
```

how can I do that . When I use above method it gives me error

This command give me error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `)'
```

Comment: one issue I can see is that you have single quotes as part of your replacement string, which is not possible with outer single quotes of sed command.. also you want variable substitution.. so try using double quotes

Comment: Thank you Sundeep.. it works for me :) Bingo :)